# Vaadin TextField action at every key pressed

Tags: java, vaadin, textfield, keylistener, vaadin7

In Vaadin 7 there are no `KeyListener` in `TextField` only on `EnterKey` press.

I'm looking for an add-on which contains a [`SuperImmediateTextField`](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/superimmediatetextfield) but compatible with Vaadin 7.

I use Vaadin version 7.1.8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use TextChangeListener.
For example:

```
// Text field with maximum length
final TextField tf = new TextField("My Eventful Field");
tf.setValue("Initial content");
tf.setMaxLength(20);

// Counter for input length
final Label counter = new Label();
counter.setValue(tf.getValue().length() +
                 " of " + tf.getMaxLength());

// Display the current length interactively in the counter
tf.addTextChangeListener(new TextChangeListener() {
    public void textChange(TextChangeEvent event) {
        int len = event.getText().length();
        counter.setValue(len + " of " + tf.getMaxLength());
    }
});

// The lazy mode is actually the default
tf.setTextChangeEventMode(TextChangeEventMode.LAZY);
```